# golang DeepEqual: when the type of value of interface map is array, the DeepEqual is invalidation

Tags: json, go

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    nodeArray := map[string]interface{}{
        "meta": map[string]interface{}{
            "category": "paragraph"}, "content": []string{"111"}}
    // content is number as 111 or array

    b, _ := json.Marshal(&nodeArray)
    var nodeArrayTest map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal(b, &nodeArrayTest)
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(nodeArray, nodeArrayTest) {
        fmt.Println("!!!! odeArray and nodeArrayTest should be equal")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("odeArray and nodeArrayTest equal")
    }
}
```

Why when the interface map has array(content is number as 111 or array), the return of DeepEqual is false? And when the content value is a string, a map, the DeepEqual is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing out the two values, in question, we can see that they are different:

```
nodeArray = map[string]interface {}{"meta":map[string]interface {}{"category":"paragraph"}, "content":[]string{"111"}}
nodeArrayTest = map[string]interface {}{"content":[]interface {}{"111"}, "meta":map[string]interface {}{"category":"paragraph"}}
```

In particular, `nodeArray["content"]` is a `[]string` slice, while `nodeArrayTest["content"]` is a a `[]interface{}` slice.  The `reflect.DeepEqual` function does not consider these equal due to the type mismatch.

The `encoding/json` module decodes into an `[]interface{}` slice because JSON arrays can contain values of different types.

Comment: if nodeArray content is as `[]map[string]interface{}{map[string]interface{}{"aa": "bb"}}`, what kind of data type in nodeArrayTest content?

Comment: If you are decoding JSON into an `interface{}` variable, you'll get basic types for strings, integers, and booleans, `[]interface{}` for arrays, and `map[string]interface{}` for objects.  This is covered by the documentation for `json.Unmarshal`.

Answer (score -2):

```
aaa := map[string]interface {}{"meta":map[string]interface {}{"category":"paragraph"}, "content":[]string{"111","222"}}
bbb := map[string]interface {}{"content":[]string{"222","111"}, "meta":map[string]interface {}{"category":"paragraph"}}
```

It's not true.

Comment: Please do not just post two lines of code. Explain, what "is not true", and why. Otherwise your solution is difficult to understand.